# Combobox is not visually centered

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a combobox with `VerticalContentAlignment` set to `Center` however it still does not appear to be center. I realized that the problem is that it is centering off of the lower case letters, not the text as a whole. So, if you have text like `This Is An Example` and measure the top/bottom space of the lower case `e`, then it is centered. However, the capital letters make it look more top aligned. In many applications this is handled....is there any way to handle this in WPF?

Comment: can you show your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ComboBox.ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to define what your `ComboBoxItem`s should look like. You can then arrange your item content anyway that you see fit:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If that does not do what you want, you can alternatively use the [`Run.BaselineAlignment` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textrunproperties.baselinealignment(v=vs.110).aspx) for further options:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Run BaselineAlignment="TextBottom" Text="{Binding}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I've just thought... you may well be able to position the text where you want it using the `TextBlock.Margin` or `TextBlock.Padding` properties:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```